# PHP using a passed value to open a dir, not working

Tags: php, html, opendir

This is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Gallery</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
    <link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body> 
<?php
$value=$_GET["value"];
$handle = opendir("content/$value/gallery/");
while($file = readdir($handle))
{
    if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..')
    {
        do_something;
    }
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Passing value "Καθολική",
gives Warning: opendir(content/Καθολική/gallery/): failed to open dir: No such file or directory.
But if i do this :

```
$handle = opendir("content/Καθολική/gallery/");
```

it works fine.

Something to do with character encoding? How could i solve this? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The charset **Καθολική** is not supported by UTF-8 Encoding. Try removing your meta UTF-8 encoding and try like this.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Gallery</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
    <link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body> 
<?php
$value=$_GET["value"];
$handle = opendir("content/$value/gallery/");
while($file = readdir($handle))
{
    if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..')
    {
        do_something;
    }
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
static public function read($dir, $ignore = array())
    {
        $files = scandir($dir);
        $dir_contents = array();
        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            $pos = strpos($file, 'import');
            if ($file == '.' OR $file == '..' OR $pos !== false)
            {
                continue;
            }
            // Ignore files specified
            if ( ! in_array($file, $ignore))
            {
                $dir_contents[] = $file;
            }
        }
        return $dir_contents;
    }
```